How to load env variable file into Jenkins Pipeline
I feel like there should be a simple way to do this, but I can't find it.
I have a file named .env in my git repo that includes a list of variables I need in my Jenkins Agent. The variables are public things like version numbers (not passwords).
How do I load a file of variables into my Jenkins pipeline?
I am using Jenkins 2.462.1
In a linux environment without Jenkins, I could do the following to load and view my variables:
source .env
printenv

I tried adding the following to a stage in my Jenkinsfile. The variables print to the console output after the source command, but are not in the list returned by printenv.
sh "source ${WORKSPACE}/.env" 
sh "printenv"

Using sh ". ${WORKSPACE}/.env" returns the same result as sh "source ${WORKSPACE}/.env".

I really hate this answer and hope someone provides a better one, but it is the only thing I've found that makes the variables available in all stages of the pipeline.
Manually copy contents of variable file into environment block at top of pipeline.
pipeline {
  environment {
    version='1.0'
    customer='Bob'
  }
  agent { any }
  stages {

     rest of pipeline

  }
}


One of the things that can be used is the withEnv function. Usually it looks like this. A list of environment variables is passed to it.
withEnv(['ENV_VARIABLE_1=/path/to/tool']) {
    sh "echo ${ENV_VARIABLE_1}"
}

For the purpose in the question it can be modified to look something like this
withEnv(readFile('fullfilepath.env').split('\n') as List) {
    // Test the loaded environment variable by echoing ${variablenme}
    // Do other actions
    // Step - 1 step - 2 so on.
}


The example above is taken from the reference here. https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#withenv-set-environment-variables
The readfile documentation can be found here https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace

readFile('fullfilepath.env').readLines() would be more idiomatic.

I need my variables available in multiple stages of my pipeline. Can I wrap all my stages with the withEnv function? This seems a bit kludgy, but should be functional if allowed.

Update: withEnv can only be used inside of stages, so in order to use this, I would have to repeat it in each stage. Also, I can not get this function to work. The Jenkins pipeline fails at this line with no error message. I've tried adding [ ], using double quotes around file name, using hard coded full file path or variable for full file path, using .split and .readLines methods.
